# Select from nothing with Join

Tags: sql

Does SQL support using Joins with Select statements having no table reference? For example, we can say

```
SELECT 1,2,3
```

a 
with no table reference and get a result set with those values.  But is there a way to use JOIN or CROSS JOIN and get a result without a table reference? For example, is there some syntax that will allow a cross join between 2 list of numbers that will return a Cartesian product of the 2 lists, without reference to any tables?

Comment: how the db engine can know the at wich table is  related  a table without any table reference?

Comment: Why do you need a join to get those values? Just run that query and it will return those values.

Comment: This seems like an odd thing to want to do.  What is it that you're really after?  Maybe you can get some better advice if ask us about the bigger picture of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Unclear.   Is there a way to JOIN or CROSS JOIN *what* and get a result?

Comment: `SELECT 1,2,3` is not valid in Standard SQL, which always requires `FROM` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can put that select in a sub-query with alias names. Then join it.

For example, this works in MS Sql Server, MySql, PostgreSql

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 1 x,2 y ,3 z) n 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'x' AS "1", 'y' AS "2", 'z' AS "3") ch;
```

In Oracle you'd have to include a `FROM DUAL`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 1 x,2 y ,3 z FROM DUAL) n 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'x' AS "1", 'y' AS "2", 'z' AS "3" FROM DUAL) ch;
```

Regarding MS Sql Server, what I noticed more in SO answers would be the `VALUES` trick.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6)) AS n(x,y,z)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES('x','y','z')) AS ch([1],[2],[3]);
```

You can test it [here](http://rextester.com/HXFQDL20763) on rextester.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this sort of thing with derived tables..

```
select *
  from 
  (
  select 1 as ID
  UNION
  select 2 as ID
  UNION
  select 3 as ID
  ) t 
  cross join
  (select 5 as ID2
  UNION
  select 6 as ID2
  ) t2
```

Answer (score 1):

It can/does, but, WHY is the bigger question..

```
select *
from (select 1 a,2 b,3 c) a
join (select 1 d,2 e,3 f) b on 1=1


select *
from (select 1 a,2 b,3 c) a
cross join (select 1 d,2 e,3 f) b
```

Comment: Actually, it's not terribly uncommon. It's not necessary of course, but sometimes its far easier. Generically, anytime you want something not contained in the database as a cross product you would do this. My most recent was generating all of the access permissions on service calls. I had a list of service call names, but there is no table storing "create,read,update,delete" in my database as it is contextually used by the application not relational to the data.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean that makes sense!  I have just never done it that way, I'd use table variables in that sort of scenario. :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for:

```
SELECT x1.n,
       x2.n
       FROM (SELECT 1 n
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 2 n
             UNION ALL
             SELECT 3 n) x1
            CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 n
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 2 n
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT 3 n) x2;
```

Result:

```
 n |  n
-: | -:
 1 |  1
 1 |  2
 1 |  3
 2 |  1
 2 |  2
 2 |  3
 3 |  1
 3 |  2
 3 |  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that a SELECT without a FROM is non-standard SQL.

In standard SQL, the only way to "generate" some values without a table reference is to use a `values()` clause:

```
select * 
from ( values (1,2,3) ) as t(c1,c2,c3);
```

That of course can combined with any type of join

```
select * 
from ( values (1,2,3) ) as t1(c1,c2,c3)
cross join (values (3,4,5) ) as t2(x1,x2,x3);
```

will return:

```
c1 | c2 | c3 | x1 | x2 | x3
---+----+----+----+----+---
 1 |  2 |  3 |  3 |  4 |  5
```

Or an outer join:

```
select * 
from ( 
   values (1,100), 
          (2,200),
          (3,300)
 ) as t1(t1id,t2val)
   left join (
      values (1,42), 
             (2,24)
   ) t2 (t2id,t2val) on t1.t1id = t2.t2id;
```

returns:

```
t1id | t2val | t2id | t2val
-----+-------+------+------
   1 |   100 |    1 |    42
   2 |   200 |    2 |    24
   3 |   300 |      |
```